# How to differentiate between new line caused by ENTER and \n written in file using lex?

Tags: lex

File: myscanner.h

```
#define TYPE 1
#define NAME 2
#define TABLE_PREFIX 3 
#define PORT 4 
#define COLON 5
#define IDENTIFIER 6 
#define INTEGER 7
```

Input file into scanner:

```
db_type : mysql
\n
db_name : textdata
db_table_prefix : test_
db_port : a1099
```

If myscanner.l is:

```
%{
#include "myscanner.h"
int nl=0;
%}

%%
:                       return COLON;
"db_type"               return TYPE;
"db_name"               return NAME;
"db_table_prefix"       return TABLE_PREFIX;
"db_port"               return PORT;
[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
[1-9][0-9]*             return INTEGER;
[ \t]                   ;
\n                      yylineno++;
.                       printf("unexpected character\n");

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
        return 1;
}
```

Then on line 2 of input file showing error as unexpected character().
If myscanner.l is:

```
%{
#include "myscanner.h"
int nl=0;
%}

%%
:                       return COLON;
"db_type"               return TYPE;
"db_name"               return NAME;
"db_table_prefix"       return TABLE_PREFIX;
"db_port"               return PORT;
"\n"                    nl++;
[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*   {return IDENTIFIER;}
[1-9][0-9]*             return INTEGER;
[ \t]                   ;
\n                      yylineno++;
.                       printf("unexpected character\n");

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
        return 1;
}
```

Then passing myscanner.l to lex itself says an error "the rule cannot be matched at

```
\n                      yylineno++;
```

My question is:
What to do if I have to write \n in my file as combination of two characters '\' followed by 'n'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
"\\n" { /* Will match \n */ }
```